# Info logging messages not being recorded in info file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have the following logger in `python`.

Depending on the function arguments, I would like to output either `INFO` and/or `ERROR` level errors to an info and/or error log file, and/or the console.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging import Formatter

def initLogger(dirName, loggerName, infoLog=True, debugLog=True, consoleLog=True):
    try: 
        logDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Test Program')
        if not os.path.exists(logDir):
            os.mkdir(logDir)
        parentLogDir = os.path.join(logDir, dirName)
        if not os.path.exists(parentLogDir):
            os.mkdir(parentLogDir)
        infoLogDir = os.path.join(parentLogDir, 'INFOLog')
        if not os.path.exists(infoLogDir):
            os.mkdir(infoLogDir)
        errorLogDir = os.path.join(parentLogDir, "ERRORLog")
        if not os.path.exists(errorLogDir):
            os.mkdir(errorLogDir)

        infoLogFilepath = os.path.join(infoLogDir, loggerName + "Info.log")
        debugLogFilepath = os.path.join(errorLogDir, loggerName + "Error.log")

        LOG_FORMAT = ("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d")

        debugHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=debugLogFilepath,maxBytes=5000000, backupCount=100)
        debugHandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        debugHandler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        infoHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=infoLogFilepath,maxBytes=5000000, backupCount=100)
        infoHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        infoHandler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        UTHLogger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
        if infoLog is True: 
            UTHLogger.addHandler(infoHandler)
        if debugLog is True: 
            UTHLogger.addHandler(debugHandler)
        if consoleLog is True: 
            UTHLogger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        return UTHLogger
    except: 
        return False
```

I've tried adjusting some things. However:

- Only **errors** are written to the file.
- The **error** level messages appear in both the **info** and **error** log files.

In the above code, I am creating the **info** logger with the following (just like the **error** logger), where I set the level to `logging.INFO`.

```
infoHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=infoLogFilepath,maxBytes=5000000, backupCount=100)
infoHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
infoHandler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))
```

I then add that handler to my logger, just like the **error** handler, with:

```
UTHLogger.addHandler(infoHandler)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works as you designed. All is correct. First of all do not split log file in error.log and info.log - this is wrong idea no time correlation. Log file is mix of all message types.

Level `logging.INFO` mean INFO and higher so ERROR and CRITICAL, WARNING - it works correctly - level is not filtering == but >=.

One log file is enough. You can write custom logger but please do not do it if you really not need it - such logger can filter as you want but as said it is not need in 99% cases. Keep it simple.

Comment: I see, thanks. However, as I mentioned, the problem is INFO is not being written, even though I set my logging level to logging.INFO

Comment: Mark answer as solving problem :) Maybe INFO is not being written but maybe it is impossible rather - maybe it is never called. You can check if logger has level and handler has level to set - for me is easy but I know logging very good. Check if setLevel always on handler and is not propagated since it can be propagated.